# Notepad++ - match only lines that only contain CAPITAL LETTERS(or whitespace)

Tags: regex, notepad++

So, something like [A-Z] will match capital letters.  How can I match lines that are entirely in capitals(or have whitespaces/whitespace-like entities)?  So, in the example below, I want to eradicate the first line and keep all the rest...

```
EVIL WIZARD
Ye insolent peasant swine!
By the demonic creatures
Resident in my ancient beard
Ye shall know true misery
Before this day is done!

[EVIL WIZARD laughs maniacally as hordes of rodents eat everything in sight]
```

Given my screenplay writing skills, maybe a regex to remove all the text would be more appropriate, but hey...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `^([A-Z\s]+)$` regex to select lines that only contain words in UPPERCASE (but no punctuation).

[image]

If you want to select lines with uppercase words, you can use `\b[A-Z]+\b` regex.

[image]

Do not forget to select **Match Case** option!

Comment: Perfect, thanks!  Is there a nice cheatsheet for this sort of stuff anywhere?